# Enabling Javascript Scripts in my C# code on IIS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis

I have some Javascript scripts in my ASP code that isn't working when I host it on Information. I tried enabling static content and setting Authentication to Anonymous Authentication. I don't have any separate JS files that I need to run, but .js is also enabled on MIME.

```
  protected void GetDateCal_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["textbox"] != "")
        {
           
            string strScript = "<script>window.opener.document.forms[0].ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_" + Request.QueryString["textbox"].ToString() + ".value = '";
            strScript += GetDateCal.SelectedDate.ToString();
            strScript += "';window.opener.document.forms[0].submit();self.close();";
            strScript += "</" + "script>";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock( this.GetType(), "Calendar_ChangeDate", strScript);

        }

    }
```

Comment: You should learn that ASP.NET code is running on the server side, not within the browser. So, when you try to attach certain JavaScript code to browser side and expect it to work the way you like, you need to follow the post back model carefully and ensure the JavaScript snippets are indeed inserted to the right place in the browser. That's not going to be a short answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would either use the "true" tag to automatic surround your js code with script tags.

And, any "" character in a c# string will be escaped, so use @ for your strings.

eg:

```
       string strScript = "<script>window.opener.document.forms[0].ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_" + Request.QueryString["textbox"].ToString() + ".value = '";
        strScript += GetDateCal.SelectedDate.ToString();
        strScript += "';window.opener.document.forms[0].submit();self.close();";
        strScript += @"</" + "script>";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock( this.GetType(), "Calendar_ChangeDate", strScript);
```

or, consider dropping the script tags, and use this:

```
        string strScript = "window.opener.document.forms[0].ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_" + Request.QueryString["textbox"].ToString() + ".value = '";
        strScript += GetDateCal.SelectedDate.ToString();
        strScript += "';window.opener.document.forms[0].submit();self.close();";

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Calendar_ChangeDate", strScript,true);
```

So, "" in any string tends to be ignored, or escaped.

Use @ for such strings, but probably better is to simple include the true tage in the Register script block, and it will surround the js code with script tags for you.

Comment: It seems like the error is coming from ```ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_" + Request.QueryString["textbox"].ToString() + ".value```.  For some reason that value is undefined.